# Ethics and readability of using ternary operator for method calls

Tags: python, ternary-operator

The standard use of the ternary operator is, i.e.:

```
a = 1 if some_condition else 2
```

Just today, I realized something like this is perfectly legal:

```
do_something() if some_condition else do_something_else()
```

For example:

```
print(1) if a == 1 else print(2)
```

instead of:

```
if a == 1:
    print(1)
else:
    print(2)
```

In my opinion, this is more compact, readable and prettier. I see that it would be harder to get return values from this type of expression (perhaps the way would be to wrap everything in parentheses). What do you think?

P.S. I know it's not typical Q&A content, but I have never even seen this use of the ternary operator mentioned, and I think it clearly improves some aspects of Python coding.

Comment: I won't go on my rant, but if you look up carrying out side effects via ternarys, you'll see many examples of why it isn't great practice. Python's ternary is, Imo, more readable than the `? :` variant, but it's still not proper.

Comment: I think it just as clearly doesn't. This is the very definition of a primarily opinion-based answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using ternary operator just for side-effects pretty confusing. The expression is supposed to *return* something (reminds me of [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects): answer is *no*)

You could rewrite:

```
print(1) if a == 1 else print(2)
```

like:

```
print(1 if a == 1 else 2)
```

or rewrite:

```
do_something() if some_condition else do_something_else()
```

to:

```
(do_something if some_condition else do_something_else)()
```

so the ternary expression *returns* something that is used by a side-effect expression.

Comment: The issue is, IMHO, that it is too easy to confuse with `print(1); if a == 1 print(2)`, without providing much benefit.